# Problems with understanding xをyに完成する

Tags: grammar, verbs, particle-に, parsing

In the definition for 小説 I found (in bold):

> 文学の一形式。散文体の文学で，一八世紀以後，近代市民社会の**生活・道徳・思想を背景に完成した**
>
> > lit. Form of literature. Is prose literature and, from (and after) 18th century, modern civilizations xxx

I’m unsure about the bolded part. I know 完成する is almost always intransitive in Japanese ([Difference between 完成させる and 完成する (transitive usage only)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27454/difference-between-%e5%ae%8c%e6%88%90%e3%81%95%e3%81%9b%e3%82%8b-and-%e5%ae%8c%e6%88%90%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-transitive-usage-only)). But that confuses me more, because there is a を particle there.

How should I, here, interpret xをyに完成する？

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20854/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16288/9831 ( see also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33562/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39830/9831 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XをYに doesn't have much to do with the valency of 完成する. Rather 近代...思想を背景に modifies 完成した as an adverbial phrase, meaning *(Novels) was established with 近代..思想 as background*.

The following examples should help to see the pattern.

- 彼は貯金を元手に起業した. *He started a company with his savings as the starting capital.*
- 彼は忙しさを盾に家事をさぼっている. *He doesn't do chores, using busyness as an excuse (lit. with busyness as a shield).*
- 彼は親の地位を後ろ盾に出世した. *He made his career with the support of his parent's status.*

I think generally it is a good starting point to think *XをYに = with X as Y*.

---

Note the relevant definition of [背景](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%83%8C%E6%99%AF/#jn-173659) here:

- 物事の背後にある事情。また、裏から支える勢力。

Comment: Thanks, I was actually also very puzzled about if the 背景 here was about the background, as in «scenery in a movie». *Now* I got the relevant definition!